# Two small chapters side by side on one page

Tags: sectioning, positioning, chapters

I've got two very short chapters and I want them to appear side by side on the same page like being arranged in a two column layout. I've got other chapters before and aftere these two which should appear in the usual layout.

```
\chapter{Normal ones}
normal content
\chapter{First short}
second content
\chapter{Second short}
second content
\chapter{Normal ones}
normal content
```

I want them to appear like this

> **Normal ones**
>
> normal content
>
> **First short          Second short**
>
> First content        Second content
>
> **Normal ones**
>
> normal content

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea without a page break. If you edit the text before it, these may end up spilling onto a new page and making matters worse.

Comment: The "usual layout" features at least one page break before each chapter.

Comment: @Mark S. Everitt: `\begingroup` and `\edngroup` will avoid this, I guess. At least it worked for me.

Comment: You've asked four questions so far, have received answers to all of them and have accepted an answer in two cases. However, you've only cast one vote so far. While accepting an answer need not be done in every case, upvoting the helpful ones should be done.

Comment: @Meinzlein I don't know what document, you are writing, but the sectioning needs some thought. Having 4 chapters show up on one page or even two, points to the need for some careful thinking about how you structured your document. Can you produce a scan from a book? I think you are looking after a two column layout overall.

Comment: @Yiannis Lazardes: I write a math document. I would like to have the Greek and Old-German alphabet as a litte table in the appendix. Since these are just two chapters with to very "thin" kind of tables I would like to put them side by side to have one page with kind of "vocabulary".

Comment: @Meinzlein -- Thanks, this is an easy problem to solve then. Frankly speaking, all you need is two tables, with an Appendix heading each. Thin tables don't look very good in type, consider displaying them horizontally.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need and I think the multicol solution from below sound right for this..

Answer (score 8):

Use the [multicol](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package and its `multicols` environment. (Note: The `\columnbreak` macro is defined by `multicol`; to achieve a column break in "normal" `twocolumn` mode, you'd use `\newpage`.)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{multicol}
\raggedcolumns
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\chapter{bla}

\lipsum[1]

\columnbreak

\chapter{blubb}

\lipsum[1]

\end{multicols}

\chapter{foo}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: In response to your edited question: You'll need a large page for such a layout (at least without changing `\chapter`s spacing), but here we go:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{multicol}
\raggedcolumns
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}

\usepackage[hscale=0.8,vscale=0.9]{geometry}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\sometext

\begin{multicols}{2}

\chapter{Second}

\sometext

\columnbreak

\chapter{Third}

\sometext

\end{multicols}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax

\chapter{Fourth}

\sometext

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Works ok. But unfortunately I had to insert a `\newpage` to have the two columns on one page. Otherwise the layout failed. What's the cause for this?

Comment: @Meinzlein: The `multicols` environment won't start a new page by default -- this is a design decision.

Comment: But I will need to start a new page to have the two chapters side by side? I can't have them on the same page with another chaper?

Comment: @Meinzlein: I'm not sure what layout you want to achieve. If your question is about more than two chapters, please edit it to include the additional information.

Comment: I added the necessary information.

Comment: `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` around the multicol-environment did the job. When the content is to large for the current page, then the content is moved to the next page. But is the content small enough it stays on the current page as desired. Without these two commands the layout got cracked.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly speaking, this is the sort of layout you should be building by hand:

[image]

From my understanding the OP wants to have two appendices with two tables. The tables hold the Greek and German alphabets. Here is a suggestion, use the `multicol` environment, as suggested also by lockstep. Forget about all the predefined formatting and do your own headings and spacing. I personally dislike `long thin tables`, and placed the alphabets horizontally and pulled them into the margins. Adjust to suit the rest of the document. You can add the headings to the table of contents by adding `addtotoc`, there are a number of posts with help for this and is fairly trivial.

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\def\sg{}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent\textbf{\Large Appendix A\\The Greek Alphabet}
\lipsum[6]
\medskip
\def\ABC{%
\begin{tabular}{|lllllllllllll|}\hline
\textgreek{a}&  
\textgreek{b}&   
\textgreek{g}&  
\textgreek{d}&  
\textgreek{e}&  
\textgreek{z}&  
\textgreek{h}&  
\textgreek{j}&   
\textgreek{i}&   
\textgreek{k}&   
\textgreek{l}&   
\textgreek{m}&
\textgreek{n}\\
a& b& g& d&  e&  z&  h&  j&  i&  k&  l&  m&  n\\
\textgreek{x}&  
\textgreek{o}&  
\textgreek{p}&  
\textgreek{r}&  
\textgreek{sv}&  
\textgreek{t}&  
\textgreek{u}&  
\textgreek{f}&  
\textgreek{q}&  
\textgreek{y}&  
\textgreek{w}& 
\sg{c}& \hbox{ } \\
x&  o&  p&  r&  s&   
t&  u&  f&  q&  y&  w& c& \hbox{ }\\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\hspace*{-3cm}\ABC

\columnbreak
\noindent\textbf{\Large Appendix B\\
The German Alphabet}
\lipsum[6]

\hspace*{-0.5cm}\ABC
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

If you need to number the tables use the package `\caption`. Floats do not work in a `multicols` environment and use `\captionof{table}{caption details ...}`.